# CORS is not working with ionic

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to send a json to a php script on a server and even though I have included header in php script to have CORS the console throws error

**error message**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.awesomegag.0fees.us/updata.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

my code :

**php**

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:            {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}
echo"hello";
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
?>
```

**My app.js**

```
.controller('datactr',   ['$scope','$http','ApiEndpoint',function($scope,$http,ApiEndpoint) {
$scope.submit=function(){
          console.log("step1");

    $http({
      method:'POST',
      url:'http://www.awesomegag.0fees.us/updata.php',
      data:{
        'name':$scope.name
      }

    }).success(function(data,status,header,config){
      console.log("step2");
      console.log(data);
    })
 });
```

I tried to make it work using proxy method by making path /api and proxyUrl to updata.php address in ionic.project and then replace url in http service to /api. I get a 500 internal server error.

Can anyone help ?

> Update: I have moved to a different server where everything works fine.I guess it is some problem with the server but have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: "The response had HTTP status code 403." That's what you should address. It's probably hitting before you event get to executing your PHP.

Comment: HTTP code 403 is forbidden so I changed the file permission to rwxrwxrwx and it resulted in same error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that your server doesn't allow OPTIONS method.

Modern browser do "pre-flight" request for cross origin request to make sure that it is allowed to do so before sending GET/POST request.

[image]

Solution: Enable OPTIONS command. Example for Apache http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_allowmethods.html

Comment: I tried to use GET method instead of a POST I get a 500 internal server error.What does that mean?

Comment: you posting a data so POST is the way don't use GET for this case.

Comment: how do you enable OPTIONS method?

Comment: That will depend on your server, if it is apache then use the link above.

Comment: I am using free web hosting from 0fees.net .But even without changing the settings in apache it should work with the php header right? source : http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Comment: try change the second line to header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST,OPTIONS');

Comment: I chaned it.But it still shows the same 403 forbidden error.Do you suggest moving to another server? please suggest one if you do so.

Comment: try it on your local server, if it is work then the issue is with server configuration.

Comment: It works fine with my localserver.I guess there is problem with the webserver.